# phpMyAdmin Error Message

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, message

Getting this error when I try and access PHPmyAdmin

Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

I refreshed browser settings and even tried it in both Firefox and Chrome. Also cleared the temp folder within XAMPP.

Not sure what happened. I was able to access it before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the log files.

Comment: I have 6. Any one in particular? The list is:
access_log
authdigest_shm.3557
error_log
httpd.pid
php_error_log
ssl_request_log

Comment: Check them all and look for today's data

Comment: Found this in the access_log:

::1 - - [16/Dec/2014:19:32:23 -0800] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1049

Comment: Have you checked that the folder configured in your PHP configuration for  `session.save_path` ? -- verify that it exists and has proper permissions.